# Back and book etymology

Tags: etymology

I know, that most of you will think, that it is absurd, but please read to the end.

Sorry for my English

Introductory:

When I read the Ostrog Bible I saw, that in the OCS the verb "to unbend a book" was used (instead of "to open a book").

At the first onset I thought about a knee, because in Russian we use that verb with this noun.

Whereupon I thought, that the English/German word knee/Knie is consonant to the first part of the OCS word "kniga".

Thereupon I thought, that the Old Slavonic laguage has a borrowed words, where "ga" is a suffix (for an example, French cheval "a horse" -> Old Slavonic chevlaga/chevluga "an old horse").

Thereupon I thought, that if someone doesn't have a table he put his "kniga" on a "knee".

Thereupon I thought, that the English verb "unbend" translates to German "geradebiegen".

Thereupon I thought about Bogen (bow), Bucht (bight) and Buch (book).

Thereupon I thought, that a knee bore little comparison to a book spine.

Thereupon I got an answer, that "The English use of 'spine' for that part of a book is modern, only from the early 20th century. Before that, this part of the book was generally known as the 'back' "

Question: Does the English word "back" somehow relate to "book"? I can not imagine a book without a back.

The official etymology:

[back](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/back#Etymology_1): from Proto-Germanic *baką possibly from Proto-Indo-European *bʰogo (literally “bending”);
[book](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/book#Etymology_1): from Proto-Germanic *bōks or from Proto-Germanic *bōk

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Ger *Bogen* means *bow, curve*, and also "sheet [of paper]". That's my etymon for *book*, thanks for asking, I cannot explain it, though. *back* on the other hand I compare to *bacon*, *Backe* (cheek), *Becken* (hip, basin, pool, sink), *Becher* (beaker), so semantic extension from hip to the whole back-side. The same way the upper back, *Kreutz* ("cross", shoulders and stem) is a pars pro toto. Now please don't get exited, a cross is such a basic pattern that it is everywhere and thus has lent itself well to christian symbolism, more so than vice versa.

Comment: Oh. You've answered your own question in the question.

Comment: @HotLicks the etymology of *book* is "uncertain". While that could be referenced, the notion alone would not make a good answer. Indeed, a good summary of prior research to the question would help responders writing an answer. But it would not satisfy OP, who  rather asked for Own Research and perhaps World Building. On the other hand, a summary might encourage synthesizing a theory from the overview and give a false sense of completeness. OP has shown their prior research. More of it wouldn't help. Whereas showing the research that others have done prior to OP is part of what OP is asking for

Comment: because it is in essence asking whether the hypothesis is viable to work with, hence subjunctive *could*. In principle this questions methodology and as such belongs on Linguistics.SE.

Comment: @vectory - I don't see any source that lists the etymology of "book" as "uncertain".  Both Oxford and Etymology Online say "Old English bōc (originally also ‘a document or charter’), bōcian ‘to grant by charter’, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch boek and German Buch, and probably to beech (on which runes were carved)", or something thereabouts.

Comment: @HotLicks The top answer mentions "phonetic difficulties"; The semantic gap is wide, too. PIE \*bʰeh₂ǵús "beech", according to wiktionary, has only reflexes in western IE languages, which seems spurious. If it did not participate in all respective sound changes, that would hint at a later word of trade. While writing is deemed a rather late invention, please consider whether *beech* is a derivative of *book* instead. I mean *Buche* sounds like a derivative of *Buch*.

Comment: Since somebody had asked, now deleted, a question about a connection between AGr. *konu* "twig" and a similar Russian word for "article" over on Linguistics.SE, I noticed *bough* "twig, branch", PIE \*bʰeh₂ǵús, which looks very, very similfar to \*bʰeh₂ǵʰús "beech". The irony here is *article* < *artus* "joint; (poetic) limb". So, get bent?! I mean, don't expect that to be an explanation, but allow for some curiosity maybe.

Answer (score 2):

No.

> [back (n.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/back)
>   Old English bæc "back," from Proto-Germanic *bakam
>
> [book (n.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/book)
>   Old English boc "book, writing, written document," generally referred (despite phonetic difficulties) to Proto-Germanic *bōk(ō)-, from *bokiz "beech"
>
> – both from Etymonline.com

They are superficially similar in English, having a single syllable b–k, but come from different roots.

The resource [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/) is recommended, especially if you do not have access to the OED.

Comment: "phonetic difficulties", what about the semantic gap? You should mention--and OP should mention if they knew--that e.g. wiktionary lists "Proto-Germanic *baką, possibly from Proto-Indo-European *bʰogo (literally “bending”)" under *back*. So two unknowns can't give a definite answer, and the question is thus legitimate. Although, OP should not expect much more than this as an answer. An opposing answer concludin "yes" would be difficult to come by and worthy of more prestigious venues. The middle ground, "I don't know" does not need to be posted. That leaves chit-chat

Comment: @vectory I have no idea what the ‘phonetic difficulties’ Etymonline allude to are: there are no phonetic difficulties. There are some _morphological_ difficulties (why does the derived sense ‘book’ appear to be an athematic stem whereas the primary sense ‘beech’ appears to be a thematic derivation?), but they are not insurmountable, and there are parallels. As for the semantic gap, there isn’t one. It is so common for names of writing materials to spawn forms referring to the thing written that it might almost be called standard (cf. Latin _liber_, _cōdex_, Sanskrit भूर्ज _bhūrjá-_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I see no phonetic difficulties either, for lack of knowledge at least, and it may be that they meant morphologic. Yet again I don't know what you mean, although I brought up the point myself before, but you might mean something else. Noticing that Ger. *Buche* is similar to a lot of other feminine tree names that end with a regular feminine *-e* Ablaut, that however may also be a genitive morpheme. While \*boks "book" may--to an English speaker at least--look like a genetive form, too. That is, I'm puzzled by the PGem forms \*boks "book", \*boko, \*bokijaz "beech".

Comment: I found that rebracketing \*bōkastabaz (Ger *Buchstabe*, En. "book stafe, letter, alphabet-letter"?) gives *tabaz*, quite comparable to Lat. *tabula*, *table, tablet*, Ger. *Tafel* "black board, table", especially notable for the sense *list of figures* either way. That leaves \*bokas which might contract to \*boks. Incidentally my neighbor has a door sign engraved in the cross-section cut from a tree branch. But this could be made from pretty much any wood. Why should the birch be symbolic? Neither *liber* nor *codex* derive from a specific tree.

Comment: Compare also *Buchsbaum*, "box-tree", *[box](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/box)* and *letter box*, but also *bosch* "woods, forest" and *bush*, *brush*. Due to the opening question about *bending and flexing* compare *bow, arch* and the *archer's bow* as something we know to be adorned with etchings, and spiritually significant. The sign *A* turned sideways even looks like a bow (or an eye, or a dead cow, ...)

Comment: We also say *shoot a message*, though I am not aware of any cognates.

Comment: Regarding this answer, *bæċ* means "birch", too. The diacrit notes a velar /x/ I guess. What modern English speakers can't pronounce and frequently render as /k/.